# Time limit exceed, I don't know what's causing it

Tags: java

> this is my code and it is giving time exceed limit.

```
class Solution {
public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
    int length = prices.length-1;
    int buy =0, sell =0;
    int profit =0;
    for(int i=0; i<=length; i++){
        while(prices[i] <=prices[i+1]){
            buy = prices[i];
        }
        while(prices[i] > prices[i+1]){
            sell = prices[i];
        }
    profit = buy-sell+profit;
    }       
    return profit;
}
```

}

> below is the provided solution

```
public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
    int i = 0, buy, sell, profit = 0, N = prices.length - 1;
    while (i < N) {
        while (i < N && prices[i + 1] <= prices[i]) i++;
        buy = prices[i];

        while (i < N && prices[i + 1] > prices[i]) i++;
        sell = prices[i];

        profit += sell - buy;
    }
    return profit;
```

}

> Why is my approach giving time limit exceed and not the provided solution?
> both are similar...

Comment: The internal while loop doesn't increment the loop-invariant i, so once this loop starts `while(prices[i] <=prices[i+1])` , it never exits.

Comment: If `prices[i] <= prices[i+1]` is true for even once, it will lead to infinite iterations as you are not moving ahead.

Answer (score 3):

In your inner `while` block,it will never finish or exit,that's the reason

```
  for(int i=0; i<=length; i++){
        while(prices[i] <=prices[i+1]){ // loop won't finish
            buy = prices[i];
        }
        while(prices[i] > prices[i+1]){ // loop won't finish
            sell = prices[i];
        }
    profit = buy-sell+profit;
    }
```

Comment: Right, though one of the two loops is/would have been skipped as the loop conditions are complementary.

Comment: Okk, but why do we need to mention again in the inner while loop that  I<N,   I mean that it is declared in the main while loop( i<N) ,  If I don't write the conditon in inner while loop that i< N it is showing runtime error..

Comment: @Atharva It's used to reduce the compare count